# A type of sequence inversion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inverse, lagrange-inversion

I'm reading a textbook which basically has the sequence
\begin{align*}
a_ n = c_n b_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} w_k b_k
\end{align*}
and it proceeds to show the inversion of $a_n$ with respect to $b_n$ is
\begin{align*}
b_n = \frac{1}{c_n} a_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \tilde{w}_k a_k
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{w}_n$ are coefficients to be determined that is a function of $w_1, \cdots, w_n, c_n$. The textbook proceeds to find the coefficients via comparison and substitutions. I'm wondering if there is some sort of inversion theorem that would automatically determine these coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With general $a_{n}, b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$, where $c_{n} \neq 0$, then the best that can be shown is
\begin{align}
b_{0} &= \frac{a_{0}}{c_{0}} \\
b_{1} &= \frac{a_{1}}{c_{1}} \\
b_{2} &= \frac{a_{2}}{c_{2}} - \frac{w_{1}}{c_{1} \, c_{2}} \, a_{1} \\
b_{3} &= \frac{a_{3}}{c_{3}} - \frac{w_{2}}{c_{2} \, c_{3}} \, a_{2} + \left( \frac{w_{1} w_{2}}{c_{1} c_{2} c_{3}} - \frac{w_{1}}{c_{1} c_{3}} \right) \, a_{1}.
\end{align}
This takes the form
$$b_{n} = \frac{a_{n}}{c_{n}} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \phi_{k}^{n} \, a_{k}.$$

With some relation between $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$, and/or $c_{n}$ then it may be possible to use a generating function, difference operator, etc., to invert the series. Most often it ends up being that a pattern from the first few term is developed.